# How to install additional ros packages in a docker ros container?

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

Recently, I downloaded Docker in my Mac and I pulled the latest ROS container (which is the kinetic-ros-base).
I have developed a stack for my robot which includes a URDF description.

URDF is not part of the res-base distribution and cannot catkin_make my workspace.

I tried to apt-get the URDF but it cannot find in the cache. Probably, I need to find a different way to add in ROS.

Does anybody have any idea?

Regards,
Angelos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266421/how-to-install-additional-ros-packages-in-a-docker-ros-container?/) by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you run apt-get update before apt-get install? Many Dockerfiles wipe the apt cache to reduce image size.

So you don't have to reinstall urdf every time your start your container, you could make your own image with a Dockerfile something like this:

```
FROM ros:kinetic-ros-base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-urdf && apt-get clean
```

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2017-07-15**:
Thanks Ed, worked nice - These are my first days using docker and I didn't know that!

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2017-07-20**:
We also wipe the them to prevent users from accidentally using stale or expired caches that could otherwise indeterminate break other dependent docker builds. This also helps prevent users from writing Dockerfiles with bad practices, such as relying on caches from the parent image.